# Is there an app/tool/setting for reading tiny websites?

Tags: browser, internet

I hate visiting websites that lack mobile views. Two examples are [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=home) and [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/). They have huge amounts of navigation/advertising on the sides, and the actual article text is ridiculously small. Even zooming in does not help.

Is there something on Android similar to iPhone's reader feature? I'd like to strip a site's bad layout and read just the main text (larger font, wrap-around based on my screen width, etc.).

For what it's worth, I'm on a Galaxy S III.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I have for now is the app [Readability](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readability) available from Google Play Store:

> Readability turns any Web page into a clean view for reading now or later on your computer or Android device. With the Readability app, you can catch up reading you've saved with the free Readability add-on for your Web browser. Already a favorite on Kindle e-readers, now you can enjoy the benefits of Readability on your Android devices.